# Android How to delete MediaPlayer perfectly

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to develop a simple test project that plays sound when I tap the button and stop automatically after a few minutes after playing the sound.

Here is a code snippet:

**Code for playing:**

```
if (mPlayer != null) mPlayer = null;

mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shush_v2);

mPlayer.setLooping(true);

mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
     @Override
     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
          mediaPlayer.start();
     }
});
```

**Code for stopping:**

```
if(mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {               
     mPlayer.stop();

     mPlayer.reset();

     mPlayer.release();

     mPlayer = null;
}
```

But sometimes I can still hear two sounds playing after I've stopped the sound.

Have so ever seen this behaviour before?

Answer (score 1):

You should clear your media player.

```
  //example usage of clearing media player when its over.
  ourSong.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        clearMediaPlayer(mp);
    }
  });
  //You can use this to stop media player.
  private void clearMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer mp){
    if(mp!=null){
          mp.stop();
          mp.release();// this will clear memory
          mp = null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PlayerApp extends Activity {
    Button btnStart;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

    // Use the handler to stop the Player, after specific time
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_app);
        btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                // Initialize Player and start it.
                // Call the Handler same time.
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.test);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                startHandler();
            }
        });
    }
    private void startHandler()
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // if Player is not null, then Stop it and Reset Null.
                if(mediaPlayer!=null)
                {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer = null;

                }
            }
        }, 2500);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Jaspreet
I checked your answer and tried it, but same
here is full my code.

Comment: https://github.com/SelfnessAid/BabyShusher---Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/babyshusher/babyshusher/com/babyshusher/MainActivity.java